# Explanation of objects moves and borrowings int rev(), chars() and next()

Tags: rust, move, borrow-checker

Hy, all. In my experiments to understand the rules of the move and borrow operations I wrote following code:

```
let company:&str="TutorialsPoint";
let test_chars = company.chars(); // move
let test_chars_1 = company.chars(); // move
let test_chars_rev = &test_chars_1.rev(); // move --explicit type here is &std::iter::Rev<std::str::Chars<'_>>
let test_chars_rev_next = test_chars_1.rev().next(); //move --creates an error that the line before a move occurred
let test_chars_rev_next_copy = test_chars_rev_next;
println!("Char indices test reverse: {:?}",  test_chars_rev);
println!("Char indices test reverse: {:?}",  test_chars_rev_next);
```

Now in my logic. the following line should be a borrow not a move.

```
let test_chars_rev = &test_chars_1.rev(); // move
```

But this creates a weird situation. I expected the the & operator creates a borrow operation and the move basically Self -> Self move. But this seems not to be the case. If the move still occurs what does the & deliver a new reference to a new moved object, or is the object still the same just this owner ship concept kicks in (ownership transfer from test_chars_1 to test_chars_rev)?

How do I have to envision the ownership in this case like a reference being moved around or is there a magic trick in the compiler who is keeping track of the things?

Of course I tried out the following scenario.

```
let test_chars = company.chars(); // move
let test_chars_1 = company.chars(); // move
let test_chars_rev = test_chars.rev(); // move 
let test_chars_rev_next = test_chars_1.rev().next(); //move
let test_chars_rev_next_copy = test_chars_rev_next;
println!("Char indices test reverse: {:?}",  test_chars_rev);
println!("Char indices test reverse: {:?}",  test_chars_rev_next);
```

Here everything works. But the result is a bit awkward.

```
Char indices test reverse: Rev { iter: Chars(['T', 'u', 't', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'l', 's', 'P', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't']) }
Char indices test reverse: Some('t')
```

The second line is especially mind boggling. I made a next() operation and suddenly I do not have the Chars to write out, but only 1 char. Why is that so? I took a look at the implementation of the next() function it seems normal.

Comment: Note that [`Iterator::rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) takes `self` by value, so the simple fact of calling `foo.rev()` will move `foo` whatever you do with the returned value.

Comment: As to your second question, calling `next` returns the next element from the iterator (and advances the iterator itself, but since you are discarding the iterator you can't see it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important thing to look at when trying to figure out if a method performs a move or a borrow is to look at its signature.

The method `chars` on `&str` has the [following signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars):

```rs
pub fn chars(&self) -> Chars<'_>
```

As you can see by the `&` used in `self`, this method *borrows* the value it's called on, to return a struct called `Chars` which implements the `Iterator` trait (where the `next` method comes from).

If you look at the [signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) for `rev`, which comes from the `Iterator` trait you'll see it *moves* the value it's called on:

```rs
fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self>
```

Another thing to note is that putting an `&` before a variable will extract a reference to it, it does not make the operation borrow instead of move. The operation move or borrow behaviour is baked into its signature.

So what's going on is the following:

```rs
let company: &str = "TutorialsPoint";
let test_chars = company.chars(); // borrow
let test_chars_1 = company.chars(); // borrow
let test_chars_rev = &test_chars_1.rev(); // move and then `&` extracts a reference
let test_chars_rev_next = test_chars_1.rev().next(); // tries to use a moved value, error (value moved to `test_chars_rev`)
let test_chars_rev_next_copy = test_chars_rev_next;
println!("Char indices test reverse: {:?}",  test_chars_rev);
println!("Char indices test reverse: {:?}",  test_chars_rev_next);
```

You can check that the calls to `chars` are borrows because you called the method on `company` but you still used `company` again afterwards.

The last thing is that the `next` method (defined in [Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next)) returns `Option<Self::Item>`, not the iterator itself. That is why when you fix the ownership error, you find yourself with an iterator on the first print and a single `Option` value on the second print.

Comment: As a more explicit example of what is going on with `&test_chars_1.rev()`, the code is the equivalent of `&(test_chars_1.rev())` and *not* `(&test_chars_1).rev()` (which doesn't work, because it's then trying to move out of a shared reference)

Comment: @Herohtar thnx for the clarification of the "order of precedence" idea. I will definitively try the code out.

Comment: @Francisco Aguirre thank you for the clarification of the & and borrow functionalities, I have read the documentation on the borrowing again, and it is still confusing. For me your answer is way better.

Comment: One tiny thing in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html), says:

The first mutable borrow is in r1 and must last until it’s used in the println!, but between the creation of that mutable reference and its usage, we tried to create another mutable reference in r2 that borrows the same data as r1.

So if I understood you correctly borrow is the process of getting the reference, but the & is the operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
let test_chars = company.chars(); // move
```

Borrows `company`, creates an iterator and moves this iterator into `test_chars`.

```
let test_chars_rev = test_chars.rev(); // move
```

Moves `test_chars` into `rev` which returns a new iterator that is moved into `test_chars_rev`.

```
let test_chars_rev_next = test_chars_1.rev().next(); //move
```

Moves `test_chars_1` into `rev` which returns a new iterator that is moved into a temporary, then `next` borrows that temporary and returns its first value that is moved into `test_chars_rev_next`. The temporary is then discarded.

```
let test_chars_rev_next_copy = test_chars_rev_next;
```

Copies `test_chars_rev_next` into `test_chars_rev_next_copy`. This is a copy, not a move, because `test_chars_rev_next` has type `Option<&char>` which implements `Copy`.

Comment: Ok, this is an description that should be in the official documentation as an example. Thank you for the patience. Basically I need to check for types if certain traits are implemented otherwise I wont know if they are moved or copied.